# Raspberry pi cannot ping router or internet addresses over wifi bridge

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, raspberry-pi

I recently set up a WNR2000v3 router running DD-WRT as a sort of repeater bridge using the "Atheros" version of [this tutorial](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge) (we'll call this 'router 2'), which is repeating a Medialink Wireless-N router (we'll call this 'router 1'). This works perfectly for my android phone and Windows computer both over the wifi and when directly connected via ethernet, but when I plug in my Raspberry pi, either when running Raspbian (wheezy) or Raspbmc, I cannot get any connection outside the local network.

The raspberry pi can ping (and be pinged by) any of the other devices on the local subnet, including 'router 2', into which it is directly connected, and it's able to get DHCP from the router 1, but when I try and ping router 1, I get "Destination Host Unreachable", and if I try pinging anything on the internet like google.com, superuser.com, I similarly get "Destination Host Unreachable".

Here's another computer on the network:

```
ping 192.168.0.100
PING 192.168.0.100 (192.168.0.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.100: icmp_req=1 ttl=127 time=38.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.100: icmp_req=2 ttl=127 time=1.67 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.100: icmp_req=3 ttl=127 time=1.73 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.100: icmp_req=4 ttl=127 time=3.56 ms
--- 192.168.0.100 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.672/11.418/38.705/15.772 ms
```

Here's router 1:

```
ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.107 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.107 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.107 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.107 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.107 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.107 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 7007ms
pipe 3
```

192.168.0.107 is the address of the Raspberry Pi:

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:db:c9
          inet addr:192.168.0.107  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3753 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1262 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:595127 (581.1 KiB)  TX bytes:112407 (109.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:27703 (27.0 KiB)  TX bytes:27703 (27.0 KiB)
```

Here is the routing table:

```
sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

And here is the DHCP request:

```
sudo dhclient -v eth0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/xx:xx:xx:xx:db:c9
Sending on   LPF/eth0/xx:xx:xx:xx:db:c9
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK from 192.168.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.0.107 -- renewal in 274691 seconds.
```

Everything else works fine, but I've tried this rapsberry pi with two different images (Raspbmc and raspbian) and two different raspberry pis and no configuration works. The raspbian image has been tested as working when directly connected to Router 1. This problem seems very similar to [this unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/319296/why-does-pinging-a-local-router-return-destination-host-unreachable) from two years ago, except that in that case it seems that he was using wifi for the device that failed to connect, and he was actually getting some intermittent connectivity. Also the ping response there was from the router, not the device. What could be causing this problem?

**Edit:** I should also note that the two different raspberry pis had different IP addresses, one of which was IP-MAC bound, and there were no IP collisions that I saw in the DHCP table, but the same problem on each.

**Update**: I have determined one potentially interesting thing, which is that when MAC Address Cloning is turned off, the repeater bridge ceases to function - the only thing that can ping the raspberry pi is router 2, and there's no connectivity (or access to router 1) from anything connected only to router 2 - including the Windows machine. However, the mac address that is being cloned is the same mac address that is actually used by the interfaces of router 2 anyway (according to the "status" page). I have power cycled both router 1 and router 2 twice and it makes no difference. I do not understand why MAC address cloning is relevant here. With MAC Address cloning off, when I ssh into the router itself, the router can ping the Raspberry pi, but not router 1.

One other small thing is that when MAC Address cloning is on and I can actually ping other computers on the network, arping returns the same mac address for every device that's responding to pings.

**Update 2:** From checking the syslog values, I found that there was this error message relating to the MAC address:

```
Jan  1 00:00:08 Router 2 kern.err kernel: [    6.770000] ath: eeprom contains invalid mac address: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Jan  1 00:00:08 Router 2 kern.err kernel: [    6.780000] ath: random mac address will be used: fa:55:da:33:19:a9
```

Apparently this is a [known problem](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=709328) that people are solving using MAC address cloning. I'm not exactly sure why the random MAC addresses are a problem, and what other consequences MAC address cloning is having.

Comment: If you have a wireless client to router 2, can you ping to/from the raspberry to the wireless client?

Comment: Yes. You can ping the raspberry from a wireless client on either router 1 or router 2.

Comment: On router 1, do you have DHCP or dnsmasq enabled?

Comment: DHCP yes, I don't know about dnsmasq. There's no setting for it in the webUI on router 1.

Comment: This is why NAT sucks. You should really use WDS instead. (Every device appears to have the same MAC address because NAT is being used to convince the access point that it's talking to its client.)

Comment: your router running dd-wrt, does it answer ping (for secturity reasons routers such as that often default to not answer ping) http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=14230&view=next&sid=1c2e29d7bcc398d9ae87f4f5e4ed16d3

Comment: URGENT: I did this `sudo dhclient -v eth0` and it broke my ssh connection!! I am currently 200 miles away from the raspberry! Is there anything I can do? I have asked someone to restart it but that didn't work. I had also changed the firewall on my router just before using this command!

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the detailed problem description.

As I suggested on the thread you opened in [raspberry pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/raspberry-pi-has-no-internet-and-cannot-ping-primary-router-when-connected-to-re) , you could check if your main router is listed in the RPi's arp table : `arp -n` or if you have the iproute2 installed: `ip neigh`.

If needed you can add the router in the arp cache with this command : `arp -s <ROUTER_IP> <ROUTER_MAC>` and see if you still have the problem

You can also check if your RPi sends the ARP request as expected by sniffing all the ARP packets. On your RPi, run : `tcpdump arp`

You could also run the same command on the DD-WRT repeater and on any other host connected on router 1. As the ARP requests are broadcasted you should see them across your lan.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when installing new Wifi Repeater. The compromised solution is set the static IP for Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one to diagnose, because of course your system seems correctly configured. So, rather than go through a lengthy list of check options, I will give  you some ideas for things to test.

One thing I would try is to change the default gateway to the router 2, rather than router 1.

Another thing is to force ping to bind to the interface eth0:

```
 ping -I 192.168.0.107 192.168.0.1
 ping -I eth0          192.168.0.1
```

These two commands are slightly different, both should be tried. Hopefully, they will give different outputs, which would be an indication of a fault.

Then I would check /etc/network/interfaces: does it contain a  couple of lines like

```
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then I would try re-starting the interface:

```
  ifdown eth0
  ifup eth0
```

and then dhclient again.

When all is said and done, one should keep in mind that 
it need not be a software problem. If you go to [this Web page](http://www.element14.com/community/message/72401) you may read the following experience:

> I had ordered another raspberry pi and just re-imaged the sd card, booted up in that one, and the internet worked fine.  I took the sd card out and put it in the old raspberry pi and hooked up the same exact cables and ethernet cord but it still didn't work....

Also, you should keep in mind that there is the possibility of a problem with the cable. Cables are not working/not working objects. A problem in RX or TX may cause many frames to be dropped, the signal quality to be marginal, and so on. In this case, protocols like TCP behave better than ICMP or UDP because they re-transmit packets which have not been received by the target, giving you the wrong impression of a properly working connection. This wrong impression lasts until you measure the connection speed, of course.

Comment: There is no difference between the response to the two ping commands. Same what I pasted above.

The /etc/network/interfaces file is empty in the raspbmc case, in the raspbian case has "auto lo" "iface lo inet loopback" "iface eth0 inet dhcp". Restarting the interface does nothing in either case.

It's definitely not a problem with the raspberry pi, because I have two different raspberry pis, neither of which work when plugged into router 2 but both of which work when plugged directly into router 1.

Answer (score -1):

Similar problem I had some time ago. My solution was editing 
`/etc/resolv.conf` file by adding `nameserver 8.8.4.4`, and by restarting interfaces using `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. It works for me.

Comment: OP mentions `Destination Host Unreachable` as error, which seems to suggest DNS works fine. A DNS error would've yielded something like `cannot resolve` or `Unknown host`.